# ¿Se puede crear en PHP un objeto fecha desde una cadena en español solamente con DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime

Si estoy recibiendo fechas formateadas en español, por ejemplo `21-Enero-2017` pensé que podía crear un objeto `DateTime` usando esa cadena e indicando al constructor de la clase `DateTime` que use un TimeZone en español.

### `Situación A: con una cadena en español`

```
$timeZone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid');
$strFechaEs="21-Enero-2017";

/* No funciona */

$fechaEs = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-F-Y', $strFechaEs, $timeZone);
echo $fechaEs->format('Y-m-d');
```

Este código no me funciona, me da el error:

> `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format()
>   ...`

### `Situación B: con una cadena en inglés`

Sin embargo, si la cadena está en inglés, funciona perfectamente:

```
$strFechaEn="21-January-2017";

$fechaEn = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-F-Y', $strFechaEn);
echo $fechaEn->format('Y-m-d');
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
2017-01-21
```

### `Pregunta:`

**¿Es posible crear un objeto fecha usando `DateTime` sin tener que usar una función que convierta el nombre del mes?**

Si la respuesta fuese **no**, ¿a qué se debe que no sea posible hacerlo? Pensaba que el parámetro `TimeZone` del constructor servía para eso.

[Aquí está el código que he probado](http://rextester.com/KGEGN70265).

Comment: El TimeZone está relacionado con la ubicación geográfica, es un componente de la fecha que se corresponde con el huso horario y no tiene relación alguna con el idioma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**, no es posible, porque espera que se proporcione una cadena que contenga un formato de fecha en inglés e intentará convertir ese formato.

Según la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php), describe los diferentes formatos de fecha que entiede el analizador de [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php), [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) y [date_create()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-create.php).

Posibles formatos del `mes`, que se pueden pasar:

```
'january' | 'february'  | 'march'     | 'april'    | 'may'      | 'june'     | 
'july'    | 'august'    | 'september' | 'october'  | 'november' | 'december' |

'jan' | 'feb' | 'mar' | 'apr' | 'may' | 'jun' | 
'jul' | 'aug' | 'sep' | 'sept' | 'oct' | 'nov' | 'dec' |

 "I"   | "II"   | "III" | "IV" | "V"  | "VI" | 
 "VII" | "VIII" | "IX"  | "X"  | "XI" | "XII"
```

Comment: Excelente. Ignoraba ese dato. Veo que en el segundo grupo hay dos posibilidades para septiembre. He formateado los meses por grupos de seis.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Buena... no me di ni cuenta