# Fatal error : Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de darle formato a la **FECHA** en php pero tengo el siguiente mensaje:

> Fatal error
> : Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in

Mi conexión a la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $db     = 'basededatos';
    $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = '';
    
    
    $conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
    
    <?
    $basededatos=mysqli_select_db($conn,$db,) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
```

Y el código donde me aparece el error es el siguiente:

```
<?php include_once("../conexionalabasededatos/basededatos.php"); ?>

<?php
    
$consultaperfil = "SELECT user, email , 
                                DATE_FORMAT (fechaAlta , '%W %d de %M de %Y' ) as fechaAl, FROM usuarios WHERE user = '$_SESSION[user]'";
$totalfilas1 = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaperfil);
$array1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalfilas1);
?>
```

Estuve leyendo que tengo que darle formato con una sentencia pasándole un parámetro al `mysqli_connect()` de algo así como:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_'"
```

Pero de todos modos me sale un **FATAL error** de que **Esta recibiendo string y no encuentra la base de datos**.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

> Lo que busco es que la fecha me salga con letras por ejemplo: "Lunes 8 de Enero"

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Este error suele ser porque la consulta es errónea, y el mysqli_query te está devolviendo false. Comprueba la consulta que se genera en la variable $consultaperfil. Muy probablemente sea la coma que tienes antes del FROM de la consulta

Comment: @Jakala a funcionado (Que raro porque antes si quite la coma pero no funcionaba y de pronto ahora si... En fin) Solo que la fecha me la entrega en INGLES alguna manera de cambiarla a ESPAÑOL? (Gracias de igual modo)

Comment: Para convertir la fecha a español, te recomendaría que no intentes configuraciones en el servidor o en PHP (eso podría afectar a otros contextos y podría ser más costoso). Puedes usar el módulo de Internacionalización de PHP (ver [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/559451/29967) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/305115/29967)) o bien crear tu propio código para convertir las fechas (ver [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90578/29967)  y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158278/29967)).

Comment: Coincido con @A.Cedano. es mejor que esa conversión la hagas en PHP y no en la consulta